# WPF MVVM: How to avoid reloading Views once they are not shown anymore

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have an application with many views and their related viewmodel. My problem is that every time I switch the displayed view (I have two different ways to do that: with a TabControl and with a ContentControl and the effect is the same) the view reaload completely and this has two main issues with my app:

1. This cause every animation I have to fire again (for example I maintain in the viewmodel what items of a TreeView are expanded and this cause to reopen it with the animation);
2. If the view I switched into has many objects to load this causes very long delays to reload it.

This is an example of how I switch from views:

XAML:

```
<Button Name="ProdNavigation"
        Command="{Binding CmdNavigateTab}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding Production}"/>

<Button Name="MachNavigation"
        Command="{Binding CmdNavigateTab}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding Machine}"/>

<Button Name="ProgNavigation"
        Command="{Binding CmdNavigateTab}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding Programming}"/>

 <ContentControl x:Name="NavigationView"
                 Margin="5"
                 BorderBrush="{StaticResource SelectedTab}"
                 BorderThickness="1"
                 Content="{Binding SelectedView}">
     <ContentControl.Resources>
         <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vmprod:ProductionViewModel}">
             <vwprod:ProductionView/>
         </DataTemplate>
         <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vmmachine:MachineViewModel}">
             <vwmachine:MachineView/>
         </DataTemplate>
         <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vmprog:ProgrammingViewModel}">
             <vwprog:ProgrammingView/>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ContentControl.Resources>
 </ContentControl>
```

ViewModel:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
protected void NotifyChange([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "") {
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

private ProductionViewModel production;
public ProductionViewModel Production => production;

private MachineViewModel machine;
public MachineViewModel Machine => machine;

private ProgrammingViewModel programming;
public ProgrammingViewModel Programming => programming;

private PlugIn selectedView;
public PlugIn SelectedView {
    get => selectedView;
    set {
        selectedView = value;
        NotifyChange();
    }
}

private void NavigateTab(object parameter) {
    if (parameter is PlugIn _plugIn) {
        if (SelectedView != null) {
            SelectedView.Selected = false;
            SelectedView.PlugInDisable();
        }
        _plugIn.Selected = true;
        _plugIn.PlugInEnable();
        SelectedView = _plugIn;
    }
}
```

Thank you very much in advance and pardon me in case the question is not clear, I am new to this.

Comment: You can't really keep Datatemplates alive the way you want. What you can do instead is for example have hardcoded usercontrols sharing the same space and toggle their visibility through their respective viewmodels

Comment: Try to use Prism with MEF/Unity to keep views alive